# how to get variable from input name without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

*hi guys i want to get name of input cuz her name have ID , and if i use form method POST to get it the page reload then i cant use popup window on the same page **sorry for my langauge :( *

`enter code here`

```
                <td>
                    <button class=" button" onclick="show()" style="vertical-align:middle" type="submit"
                        name="<?php echo $r['Id_Etudiant']; ?>" >
                        <span>Editer<i class=" fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>


                    </button>

                </td>
```

the function onclick show() , its my function js for call poppup window.

and here is my div where i need to put data ,(its my popup).

```
enter code here
<div class="background_page_modify" id="page_modify" onclick="hide()">
    <div class="page_etudiant" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
        <div class="closebtn" id="closebtn" onclick="hide()">
            <div class="circle"> +</div>
        </div>
        <div class="etudiant_box">

            <?php
```

`/*here is window popup where i wanna display my data but i cant and if i use form method POST i cant fixed my popup cuz the page is reload */`
?>

```
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read the policy article on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and then take sometime to update your post so that it contains a reasonably well written question, using the correct markup for text vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is using jquery.

You get the name of an input and you will put into your div.

```
$(document).on("click", "#inputId", function(){
    $("#yourDivId").html($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: sorry , bruh but u mean i need to use Id="inputId" on my button , i never use jquery am  beginner php but i need solution its 3th day witouth any idea  :( i can send u my code if can help me ! and thank you <3

Comment: you can edit your post and add the full code using the code button, it will be better to read and understand

Answer (score -1):

basically, if you want to prevent reload you should use JavaScript instead of PHP.

To get value from an input with some id you can use `document.querySelector('#inputId').value`

To some text into some HTML element, you can use `document.querySelector('#someElementId').innerText = 'some text';`

Eg. to copy value from input to some HTML element you could write:
`document.querySelector('#someElementId').innerText = document.querySelector('#inputId').value;`

Comment: dont work i was take jst the first id from table if i click of the 4th i get the first id :(

Comment: id should be unique per site if it is not then querySelector will just return first. You can use class selector '.someClassName' or element selector 'someElementName' combined with querySelectorAll